# Can I have conditional statements, based on server, in .htaccess file?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a dev server and live server, both running my site on Apache. In my .htaccess file, in addition to lots of mod_rewrite commands and other important things, I also have Auth access control for the live server. (The dev server is on my local Mac, so I don't need it there...)

Right now it's hard to sync .htaccess up to the live server since I can't just copy my dev .htaccess file (that would overwrite the Auth commands), so I have to manually edit the live one.

Is there a way to have a conditional in the .htaccess file? I'm imagining something like:

```
<On Live_Server>
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/lmiv/.htpasswds/.htpasswd 
  Require valid-user
</on>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close, yes. You could use an [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine) block for this. It requires that you start Apache with an additional `-D` directive, the argument to which then becomes available anywhere in the Apache configuration. For instance, if you add `-DLive_Server` to the command-line options in production, you could then do this in your configuration in all environments:

```
<IfDefine Live_Server>
  AuthName "Restricted Area"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/lmiv/.htpasswds/.htpasswd 
  Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

You could also do the reverse, and define something like `-DDev_Server` in your development environment, and invert the match:

```
<IfDefine !Dev_Server>
```

I prefer the latter, since it requires less "special" configuration for the production environment, and it doesn't require you to restart the production instance just to get the `-D` added to the command line.

Comment: Is there any way to specify a -D value in the .httpdconf file?