# How to specify command line options for XAMPP for Mac?

Tags: osx, apache-httpd, xampp

Per the answer to this question:
[Can I have conditional statements, based on server, in .htaccess file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33712/can-i-have-conditional-statements-based-on-server-in-htaccess-file/33738#33738)

I want to specify a command-line option when starting up Apache on my Mac. But my Apache is part of XAMPP-- I'm using the XAMPP app, where I click a button and Apache just starts. How can I specify a command line option? (I was hoping clicking that button trigged a script that I could edit, but I'm not able to find anything that looks like a startup script in the XAMPP folder.)